# Perl error while compiling Munin transmission plugin

Tags: ubuntu, perl

Could you please tell me what this error says?:

```
Can't locate JSON/RPC/Client.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./transmission_ line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./transmission_ line 3.
```

This is a perl plugin for munin system monitoring tool.

I'm using Ubuntu server 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tell us which system/OS/distribution you are using but generally:

You are missing the JSON::RPC::Client Perl module, you can install it

- with your package manager (yum, apt, ...) depending on your distribution (if available)
- directly from CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-RPC-0.96/lib/JSON/RPC/Client.pm (see the [instructions](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html))

**Edit**: since you are using Ubuntu you should install the [`libjson-rpc-perl`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/perl/libjson-rpc-perl) package.

Comment: Its ubuntu server 12.04

Comment: is this the right package? sudo apt-get install libjson-rpc-perl